# inverting function

Tags: functions

a) Map $f:A\rightarrow B$, where $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{2,5,8,11,14\}$ given a formula $f(x)=3x-1$. Find the map $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$
b) Map $f:R\rightarrow R^{+}$ given a formula $y=e^x$. Find the inverse map $f^{-1}$, domain and codomain of function $f$ and $f^{-1}$
My attemp is:

a) $$y=3x-1\Rightarrow \frac{x+1}{3}=y^{-1}$$
Now map $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$ where $B=\{2,5,8,11,14\}$ and $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ given a formula $\frac{x+1}{3}=y^{-1}$

b)
$$y=e^x\Rightarrow \ln x=y^{-1}$$
the map $f^{-1}$ is $\ln x=y^{-1}$

domain of the given function is $D_f=R$; codomen is $R^{+}$

domain of the inverse function is $D_{f^{-1}}=R^{+}$; codomen is $R$

I didint know it is correct.Please help me anyone. thanks for your attention and your help

Comment: can you helpme anyone, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main relation you need to solve this kind of problem is given by:
\begin{align*}
f(f^{-1}(y)) = y
\end{align*}

if we admit the function $f:X\to Y$ is bijective.

In the first case, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 3x - 1 & \Rightarrow f(f^{-1}(y)) = 3f^{-1}(y) - 1 = y \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) = \frac{y+1}{3} 
\end{align*}

Similarly, the second case can be approached as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \exp(x) \Rightarrow f(f^{-1}(y)) = \exp(f^{-1}(y)) = y \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) = \ln(y)
\end{align*}

Here I suppose that both functions are bijective over the range (which is the case, indeed).

You can try to prove it by yourself. If you have any problem, please let me know.

Comment: it shows that I acted correctly

Comment: You can upvote my answer if you think it deserves.